# Calculate a table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculated-columns

I am looking to calculate a column within a table that is being created. I need the sum field to add up the values created from the form, which is created new rows for the table upon submit. Any way I can get the  to add up the column sum? Each time a function updatetable() is run is creates another table row, and these are the rows I need calculated...currently the column holds a "184" as a holding place for where the calculation would take place.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>The real test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="html_testing.css">

  <script type="text/javascript"> <!--

 var tabBody, row, cell;
 function updateTable(){
     tabBody=document.getElementById("joe$");
     row=document.createElement("tr");
     row.setAttribute("id","js");
     cell = document.createElement("td");
     cell.innerHTML=document.forms['leds'].elements[2].value;
     row.appendChild(cell);
     if(tabBody.childNodes.length==17)
       tabBody.removeChild(tabBody.childNodes[0])
     tabBody.appendChild(row);
 }
   function updateTable1(){
     tabBody=document.getElementById("joe");
     row=document.createElement("tr");
     cell = document.createElement("td");
     cell.innerHTML=document.forms['leds'].elements[3].value;
     row.appendChild(cell);
     if(tabBody.childNodes.length==17)
       tabBody.removeChild(tabBody.childNodes[0])
     tabBody.appendChild(row);
 }



    function myFunctionJoe(){
        updateTable();
        updateTable1();
        }

    function moneymoney(){
    ('#joe$ tr:first td').each(function(){
   var $td = $(this);  

    var colTotal = 0;
    $('#joe$ tr:not(:first,.totalColumn)').each(function(){
        colTotal  += parseInt($(this).children().eq($td.index()).html(),10);
    });

    $('#joe$ tr.totalColumn').children().eq($td.index()).html('Total: ' + colTotal);
});
}

 </script>

 <body>
 <h2>Legion of Roar:</h2>
<form name="leds" id="ledSend" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
Lamp Control: <input type="radio" name="led" value="0" checked />Off
              <input type="radio" name="led" value="1" />On<br>
Winning Bid: <input type="text" name="timer" placeholder="Bid..." /><br>
Player Drafted: <input id="name" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Player Name..." /><br>
Player Position: <input id="name" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Position..." /><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Joe" onclick="myFunctionJoe();"/>

<h1>Testing some skills</h1>
<fieldset>
<table border ='1' class="inlineTable">
<thead><tr><th>Joe</th></tr></thead>
<thead><tr><th>200</th></tr></thead>
<tr class="totalColumn">
        <td class="totalCol">Spent:</td>
    </tr>
<tbody id="joe"><tbody>
</table>
<table border ='1' class="inlineTable">
<thead><tr><th>$</th></tr></thead>
<thead><tr><th>184</th></tr></thead>
<tr class="totalColumn">
        <td class="totalCol">Spent:</td>
    </tr>
<tbody id="joe$"><tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you creating so many repeated tables with so many needless `thead` elements? Is that your actual HTML or a amended version of it just for this question?

Comment: Sooo that is my actual code currently...I had created soo many tables because I wanted to keep the formatting how it was, and to create a sum or calculation on each table column. The only way I knew I could attempt to make it work was like that. Ultimately I would love to have 1 table, and from the form have the output go to the correct column and row IE: fill down. But was unsure how to go about it

Comment: Sorry I realized I had not included the CSS

Comment: what is the 200 number in the table? you want a running tally of the $ column? then there do you want that total? I don't see the relation between 200 and 184 right now.

Comment: The connection will end up being 2 different calculations. The 200 is a starting value and when there is a number (or value) added to the row it will need to be subtracted from the 200. The 184 will need to be a different calculation field. To explain this value...this table will end up being 16 rows and each row will need to have a value of at least 1, but adding up to no more than 200. So 200-16 = 184 meaning if all the other rows have 1's 1 of the rows could have a max of 184. (I apologize if my explanation was not very clear).

Comment: Yes Andrew, I do essentially want a running tally of the $ column, then simply 200 minus that running tally. Thanks!!!

Comment: I would recommend handling this by having a 'total' class on on the td for the total, then you can use a css class selector to grab all the total cells and sum.

Comment: Ryan I am looking for an example somewhere on how the selector would do the equation, what would the <td> look like ?

Comment: Ryan Gibbs I tried adding the classes, and I found something like what I just edited above. However I still cannot get the columns to add up...is my function not being called?